# How to retrieve Facebook home news feed for apps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently attempting to retrieve the news feed from my Facebook home feed to include into an app. I know this used to be able to be done with the API however I have heard that it has since been removed. Is there any other way that you know of that would work or has it been added back into the API? It doesn't make sense why they would remove it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to get a user’s feed via API. That used to be possible in the very early days (API v1), but has long since been removed.

> It doesn't make sense why they would remove it.

Apart from user privacy (I don’t want *my* posts getting analyzed by some shady app with a developer located in $godKnowsWhere, just because they appeared on the feed of a friend of mine who might be using questionable apps), Facebook considers this a “core feature” – and 3rd-party apps are not supposed to replicate those in the first place. Facebook wants to make money from showing me ads when I view my feed, so allowing any other app to perform the same functionality would just mean loss of revenue.

Comment: Would you happen to know if Instagram is that same way?

Comment: No, but with the new API you are limited to accessing Business or Creator accounts, “normal” user accounts don’t allow for API access at all any more AFAIK. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api